# Link(web page) of interstitial open over interstitial in IOS

Tags: ios, interstitial, google-dfp

I put the interstitial in my app.
In IOS, the interstitial links are opening in app. 
I need force the IOS open in browser. 
it is normal comportament? how i resolve this?

in attach files are images for interstitial and web page open over interstitial.

i get the interstitial code here: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1656921?hl=en (simple code for automatically closing an interstitial)

the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.admob.com/api/v1/google_mobile_app_ads.js"></script>
    <script>
    <!--
    function _admStartCountDown(){setTimeout('admob.opener.close()',5*1000)}
    function
    _admOnload(){if(admob.opener.isOverlayShowing()){_admStartCountDown()}else{admob.events.addEventListener('onshow',
    _admStartCountDown)}}
    if(window.addEventListener){window.addEventListener("load",_admOnload,false)}else{window.attachEvent("onload",_admOnload)}
    //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="http://uol.com.br" target="_blank">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/320x480/000/fff&text=320.480+fecha+sozinho" width="320"/>
</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you find an answer ?

Comment: We've resolve our issue with this. Now our ads opens in the safari... Actually I don't know what about automatically closing, but without this feature it works perfect. The answer you can find by the link you've provide in the last section ("Target window: new browser window"). Hope it will helps...